# Native PHP / Mysql installation on Mac, activating the PDO driver

Tags: php, mysql, pdo, mysqli

I have a custom installation on the MacOSX Lion consisting of the following:

1. Native PHP upgraded to 5.4, works like a charm.
2. Installed MySQL, being run from /usr/local/mysql-5.5.25-osx10.6-x86_64/bin/mysql, works like a charm, Workbench connects and can do ops.
3. Edited php.ini in /etc/ to activate the following:

   ```
   extension=php_mysqli.so
   extension=php_pdo_pgsql.so
   extension=php_pdo_mysql.so
   ```
4. phpinfo() says the following:

   PDO

   PDO support enabled
   PDO drivers mysql, pgsql, sqlite

   pdo_mysql

   PDO Driver for MySQL    enabled
   Client API version  mysqlnd 5.0.10 - 20111026 - $Id: b0b3b15c693b7f6aeb3aa66b646fee339f175e39 $

   Directive   Local Value Master Value
   pdo_mysql.default_socket    /var/mysql/mysql.sock   /var/mysql/mysql.sock

That means it works, yes?

Two problems though:

- No such file as /var/mysql/mysql.sock, it's in /tmp/mysql.sock. But I configured and built php with the PDO options on: --with-mysql=mysqlnd  --with-mysqli=mysqlnd  --without-pear  --with-pdo-mysql=mysqlnd  --with-mysql-sock=/var/mysql/mysql.sock. No effect if I change the ini setting to /tmp/mysql.sock, it's reflected in php.ini, but the error stays exactly the same.
- When I try to instantiate the PDO class inside PHP, this happens: 
  Uncaught exception 'PDOException' with message 'could not find driver'

When I try accessing MySQL from PHP in an old school mysqli kind of way, I get this:

Failed to connect to MySQL: (2002) No such file or directory Warning: main(): Couldn't fetch mysqli in...

What else can I try to make my PHP and my MySQL play nice?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The solution was to do the following:

1. Change .sock path in php.ini to reflect the actual path
2. **Restart your computer,** not just apache

It appears the php.ini changes did not load while doing

```
$ sudo apachectl restart
```

and needed the Macbook to reboot before it took them into account.